# Which object has lower drag?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

Two same objects,only difference are parts that are paint in red,5m long,fluid air,veloctiy up to 300km/h.

Which object has lower drag of these two and why(explanation)?

[image]

Comment: Those are not objects, they are 2-D shapes.

Comment: @StephenG Now ok?

Comment: Presumably the lower one will have less drag. Starting from the lower one, as we make the corners more jagged/sharp, the streamlines will distorted, bringing it closer to turbulence. Also, I don't know what @StephenG 's concern was, drag can still exist in 2-dimensions.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan The problem is the OP had just a little while before posted a question about drag on *cars*, which are decidely (complex) 3-D objects.

Comment: Here is a link to a slide show that I found by a quick websearch which I hope will illustrate the complexities of what you are asking about : [slideshow about drag on cars](https://www.mech.kth.se/courses/5C1211/Drag04.pdf).

Comment: @StephenG Ah okay, I get your point then.

Comment: @JohnHunter I'm not sure if you realize that the question you mention (as a duplicate) is one the OP just a short while before this one.  I think the OP is (in this question) trying to provide a simplified problem from the one he previously posted.  I'm not sure they could be called duplicates.